# Customer Community User Profile is not available in the Communities Setting | Sharing Set | Available Profiles

Tags: community, trailhead

[image]

Why ***Customer Community User*** Profile is not visible?

I am trying this

[image]

Comment: I can see `Customer Community Plus User` at the bottom. Can you scroll below that and check?

Comment: next one is *Customer Community Plus Login User*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have one sharing set per profile.  You must already have a sharing set for the profiles missing from the selection list.  Find the existing sharing set and add the additional sObject to that sharing set.

Comment: OR you can have a profile assigned into just one SharingSet at max, not more than 1. So if you have already created a SharingSet including a profile then that profile will not be available for including in any other SharingSet.